# GluNurbsSurface deprecated, what to replace with?

Tags: opengl, glu

I've been looking at the [gluNurbsSurface](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/gluNurbsSurface.xml) and [gluBeginTrim](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/gluBeginTrim.xml) for trimming and drawing nurbs surfaces as described [here](http://www.glprogramming.com/red/chapter12.html).

But from what I can see GLU is deprecated with the release of OpenGL 3.1, so what would I use to replace these methods?

If it was just an untrimmed surface, it would be easy to live without, but I would really like to know if there exist a method for the trimmed surfaces.

Comment: The problem with GLU NURBS is that they are effectively layered on top of OpenGL's old evaluator API subset. With 3.1 that subset of GL was removed in lieu of `GL_ARB_compatibility`. The thing is, this was never really hardware accelerated ... the first time this sort of functionality became standard hardware accelerated equipment was with the introduction of tessellation shaders in GL4 (which is quite a large gap). If you are in a situation where the evaluator API is gone from GL (e.g. a core profile context), you will probably need to resort to a different library for NURBS evaluation.